# How to cancel a synchonous pull request with C# client library using SubscriberServiceApiClient.Pull()?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to perform a synchronous pull operation on a subscription and would like to wait until at least one message is available. I use this code:

```
SubscriberServiceApiClient client = SubscriberServiceApiClient.Create();
SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);
PullResponse pullResponse = client.Pull(subscriptionName, returnImmediately: false, maxMessages: 10);
```

According to the [api documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberServiceApiClient.html#Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_SubscriberServiceApiClient_Pull_Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_SubscriptionName_System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_Int32_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_) when *returnImmediately* is set to *false*, the client may cancel the request. From that documentation:

> If this field set to true, the system will respond immediately even if it there are no messages available to return in the Pull response. Otherwise, the system may wait (for a bounded amount of time) until at least one message is available, rather than returning no messages. The client may cancel the request if it does not wish to wait any longer for the response.

However, I don't see how I can cancel this pull request.

When no messages are available in the subscription this call simply blocks until I get an RpcException after 10 minutes, which is the default RPC expiration:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744299/subscriberclient-pull-how-to-cancel-a-request), but the answer there was for a Java client on an old API version. I use the latest GA version (Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1) of the .NET client.

Comment: The API documentation is written with respect to "raw" clients - the RPC can be cancelled. I don't *believe* we expose any way of doing that from the C# library in a synchronous way. If you can use the async method instead, you could provide a cancellation token that you then cancel.

Answer (score 1):

The `SubscriberServiceApiClient.Pull()` method accepts an optional parameter `callSettings`, which you can use for example this way:

```
SubscriberServiceApiClient client = SubscriberServiceApiClient.Create();
SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);
PullResponse pullResponse = client.Pull(
  subscriptionName, returnImmediately: false, maxMessages: 10,
  CallSettings.FromCancellationToken(token));

// you could also specify the maximum time the Pull() method should block:
PullResponse pullResponse = client.Pull(
  subscriptionName, returnImmediately: false, maxMessages: 10,
  CallSettings.FromCallTiming(CallTiming.FromTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))));
```